# Custom progress bar doesn't update smoothly

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-progressbar

I'm trying to do a circular progress bar run smoothly but I'm not having result. The progress bar should be update in function of a timer value.

Here is how I animate the progressbar,

```
int progress = (int)(this.mCurrentTimerValue/1000);
this.mProgressBarAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this.mProgressBar,"progress",progress);
this.mProgressBarAnimation.setDuration(this.mCurrentTimerValue);
this.mProgressBarAnimation.setInterpolator( new LinearInterpolator());
```

where **this.mCurrentTimerValue** is the time in ml. For this example is 10000

And here is the result,

[image]

I want to show the progress smoothly but I can't. I tried with **ObjectAnimator.ofFloat** because the problem maybe is that I'm trying to progress in integer spaces but in that case animation doesn't work.

Here is how I customized the progress bar,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="@color/yellow"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow"
                android:startColor="@color/yellow"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="@color/green"
                android:endColor="@color/green"
                android:startColor="@color/green"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar" />
```

I read these questions but didn't help me,

- [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627543/smooth-circular-progressbar-animation-android)
- [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/make-a-progressbar-update-smoothly)
- [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766755/smooth-progress-bar-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody need a solution for this situation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220438/4930195) helped me but I admit I don't think is the best.

Answer (score 2):

use this `progressBar.setProgress(newProgress, true)`

second parameter: true to animate between the current and target values or false to not animate